# How to read the body of ssl response using BIO

Tags: c, ssl, twitter, openssl

Hello I've got a problem trying to create a twitter console app. When getting a response I've got some thrash in it.
Here my code is:

```
char new_request[1024] = "GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=4&screen_name=twitterapi HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.twitter.com\r\nUser-Agent: twitter-terminal-app$
strcat(new_request, bearer);
strcat(new_request, "\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n\0");
BIO_write(bio, new_request, strlen(new_request));

printf("%s\n", new_request);

p = BIO_read(bio, ans, 2047); // Getting header
ans[p] = 0;
printf("%s\n", ans);

char ans2[100000] = "";

p = BIO_read(bio, ans2, 10000); // Getting body
BIO_should_retry(bio);

FILE *file = fopen("result.txt", "w+");
fputs(ans2, file);

printf("%s\n%i\n", ans2, p);
```

The answer I have in body looks like that:

▒▒is▒HǿJ▒_ 
▒▒▒▒V▒▒▒▒.▒▒T▒▒f 
▒Tm▒m 
▒P▒▒1▒|▒}▒%▒▒▒▒Q^▒▒▒▒?▒cx{Չ 
F%▒C*;▒▒ŴD/#▒L▒▒▒▒?L▒A▒▒▒N▒▒ĝ▒▒▒▒$▒El▒▒▒▒X▒▒B0▒~%▒▒5▒˲@Y)GY▒ctz▒h&-▒▒▒O>AG▒▒▒l6b▒z▒:K 
▒T▒\▒▒2+▒b▒H▒&B ▒▒▒B▒qV▒▒▒▒▒▒ 
▒▒a_▒l▒?#▒o▒▒▒W▒▒u%▒▒▒;▒1M▒v▒▒L▒▒

Maybe the answer is encoded somehow and that's the problem. Tried to serf dev.twitter.com but didn't find any answer. If I use BIO_gets() instead of BIO_read() the answer is -2. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to be encoded as binary, so you'll want hex or base64 most likely....

Comment: That's what you got with your *second read.* There is nothing here that ensures that the first read read all the headers; so there is nothing here that ensures that what you get in the second read is the body; and there is nothign here that takes the slightest notice of any of the headers, for example `Content-encoding`. Don't try to implement HTTP or HTTPS yourself. It's more complex than you think. Use an existing library.

Comment: The project I'm doing is actually about implementing HTTP by myself c:

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> strcat(new_request, "\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\r\n\r\n\0");
> ...
> p = BIO_read(bio, ans, 2047); // Getting header
> ...
> p = BIO_read(bio, ans2, 10000); // Getting body
> ```
>
> ... Maybe the answer is encoded somehow

You've declared in your HTTP request that you support data compressed with gzip and that's why the server has send you the data compressed. If you would not only read and ignore the HTTP response header but actually take a look at it you would probably notice:

```
  Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Apart from explicitly allowing compressed data you are doing a HTTP/1.1 request. This means that you would also need to be able to deal with [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). HTTP/1.1 also implies that by default that connections are persistent so you would need to properly parse the header to find out where the response really ends instead of relying on connection end. You also cannot rely on a fixed size of the header or that header and body can be read with separate BIO_read calls. For example you might need multiple reads for the body or the body might already be included in the single read you do for the header.

Unless you really want to deal with all these problems yourself I recommend you better use an existing library which implements this properly and thus gets you the correct response reliably and not by chance.
If you instead want to learn how this is done I recommend you start with learning more about HTTP, i.e. by reading the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and then continue with all the standards referenced there. I suggest to start with HTTP/1.0 since this is simpler than HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The point is to learn about how http is working